# How to set a style for the Icons in a list List [Flex 3]

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I am trying to assign a style for each icon in a List component.

The traditional way to assign an icon would be to use the icon field of the item renderer, which reads the value of "icon" property in your data, for example:

```
    listData.addItem({label: "Logout", icon: "com.classpth.DefualtThemeLogoutIconClass"});
```

But i want the `DefualtThemeLogoutIconClass` to changed to another class: `LightThemeLogoutIconClass` when the theme is changed.

The only way to do this would be to use a style declaration containing a classReference to the  icon, and change its the  value in each of the CSS files of the various themes.

The question is, is there any way to assign this style to an icon in a List, something as easy as intuitive as `list[0].getIcon().setStyle("styleName");`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to extend your list with icon style and then use custom Item renderer with possibility switch an icon. So if `rendererIcon` style of your list changes you call `invalidateDisplayList()` (in `styleChanged()` of a list) and then in `updateDisplayList()` iterate all the renderers and assign new icons.

Comment: I was actually thinking on the line of your advice. I ended up defining for each icon its own style property as metatags. However, unlike what you proposed, and since my icons' styles wont change during runtime, I retrieved the style values and assigned them to the icons during initialization of the list. and the problem was solved. Thanks for the advice :)